# Aura:If results in label - field not value

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura-attribute, aura-iteration, aura-if

When using **aura:if**, I can't get the value of the field to show. Unless I'm using **lighting:outputfield** the result is the field label. Is there something else I should do to ensure the value is produced for **aura:if**? I was hoping that value would show in the **div id**, too.

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,force:appHostable" 
            access="global" 
            controller="RLC_Class" > 

<aura:attribute name="relatedListURL" type="String"/>  
<aura:attribute name="title" type="String"/>  
<aura:attribute name="criteria" type="String"/>  
<aura:attribute name="parentFieldName" type="String"/>  
<aura:attribute name="sobjectName" type="String"/>  
<aura:attribute name="ObjectName" type="String"/>  
<aura:attribute name="childRelName" type="String"/>  
<aura:attribute name="iconName" type="String"/>  
<aura:attribute name="field1" type="String"/>
<aura:attribute name="field2" type="String"/>   
<aura:attribute name="listRecords" type="sObject[]"/>  
  
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.fetchRecords}"/>  
  
<lightning:card>  

    <p class="slds-p-horizontal_small">  
          
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.listRecords}" var="item">  

            <lightning:recordViewForm recordId="{!item.Id}" objectApiName="{!v.sobjectName}" density="compact">   

<aura:if isTrue="{!v.field2 == 'Cat'}">

                <div class="slds-grid">  
                    <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-1">
                        <div>
                            <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="form-element-01" style="float:left;">Long Term Notes:</label>
                            <lightning:outputField fieldName="{!v.field1}" variant="label-hidden" style="float:left;"/> 
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                </div>  
                      
<aura:set attribute="else">
  <div id="{!v.field2}">The else result is here.</div>
</aura:set>
  </aura:if>     
            </lightning:recordViewForm>  
              
        </aura:iteration>  
    </p>  
               
</lightning:card>  
  
</aura:component>
```

Comment: So you want use div tag instead of `<lightning:outputField fieldName="{!v.field1}" variant="label-hidden" style="float:left;"/> ` ?

Comment: No - everything will stay. I want to understand why lightning:output field produces the value of the field, while the other two do not. Ideally, all three will produce the value of the field.

Comment: Which other too, I see only `div` . And `lightning:output field` will be wired with the schema based on the `objectApiName` , thus will show the expected field type, where as `div` is an `HTML` tag, not something which comes under salesforce. Is that what you were asking?

Comment: So, "<aura:if isTrue="{!v.field2 == 'Cat'}">..." and "<div id="{!v.field2}">..." will not show the value without something extra?

Comment: I am a bit confused here, `aura:if` has a totally different purpose and `<div id="{!v.field2}">` this is nothing but a div with an ID. What are you expecting these to show?

Comment: I'm expecting aura:if to show/hide a section based on the value of a picklist. I'm expecting the div id to change CSS back on picklist value.

Comment: Then div should have a class instead of `Id` right , and that class should already be in your css component. And yes `aura:if` will show or hide. Based on your question it will show if `field2` is `Cat` orElse it will go to `attribute="else"` part.